# Linq search on array of object

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to create a linq query that can be able to search through an array of objects. This is what I can do on the SQL

```
select * from Compliance c
join ComplianceDetail cd on cd.ComplianceID = c.ComplianceID
join ComplianceDetailAnswer cda on cd.ComplianceDetailID = cda.ComplianceDetailID
where cda.ComplianceQuestionValue like '%test%'
```

As you can see, the heirarchy is one `Compliance` to many `ComplianceDetail` and one `ComplianceDetail` to many `ComplianceDetailAnswer`. I want to search on the `ComplianceDetailAnswer` table but I have no idea how to do it in linq.

Here's my original code but I'm searching on the `Compliance` table itself

```
compliances = await _contextProvider.Context.Compliances
               .Where(c.IncidentReportID.ToString().Contains(searchText) || searchText == null)
               .ToListAsync();
```

This is just searching on the `Compliance` table, but I want to be able to search on its child table `ComplianceDetailAnswer`

Comment: Are your nav properties set up, or are you expected to write manual joins?

Answer (score 1):

You can compose it in LINQ easily. Here is an example using query syntax:

```
var result = from c in Compliance
        join cd in ComplianceDetail on c.ComplianceID equals cd.ComplianceID
        join cda in ComplianceDetailAnswer on cd.ComplianceDetailID equals cda.ComplianceDetailID
        where cda.ComplianceQuestionValue.Contains("test")
select new { c, cd, cda };
```

If you need to call `Skip` and `Take` simply wrap your expression to parentheses and the you can chain other LINQ methods

```
var result = (from c in Compliance
              join cd in ComplianceDetail on c.ComplianceID equals cd.ComplianceID
              join cda in ComplianceDetailAnswer on cd.ComplianceDetailID equals cda.ComplianceDetailID
              where cda.ComplianceQuestionValue.Contains("test")
              select new { c, cd, cda }).Skip(1).Take(100);
```

Comment: Great! But, I also want to add skip and take into it since it was originally meant for pagination.

Comment: @Khen no problem, simply wrap the expression into `()` and call required methods after

Answer (score 1):

Here's another answer using `System.Linq`. Each `IEnumerable<T>` supports `Take()` and `Skip()`.

As long as you do not iterate the result - in my case `compliancesWithQuestionsLikeTest` the query will not be executed, since it's just an `IQueryable` object.
Adding `Take()` and `Skip()` should therefore generate an SQL statement that has something like `TAKE FIRST 50 ROWS ONLY` and thus give you a performance benefit.

```
class Compliance
{
    public List<ComplianceDetail> ComplianceDetails { get; set; }
}

class ComplianceDetail
{
    public List<ComplianceDetailAnswer> ComplianceDetailAnswers { get; set; }
}

class ComplianceDetailAnswer
{
    public string Question { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var obj = new Compliance();
    var queryList = new List<Compliance> { obj };

    var compliancesWithQuestionsLikeTest = queryList.Where(compliance => compliance.ComplianceDetails
            .Any(complianceDetail => complianceDetail.ComplianceDetailAnswers
                .Any(answer => answer.Question.Contains("test"))));

}
```

In this sample `queryList` basically is your `_contextProvider.Context.Compliances`.

EDIT:

Please note that this query will return the `Compliance` objects in an unmodified manner. You will get only `Compliance`s containing a question with `test`. The `Compliance` objects however also contain all other question related to them in the database. The objects are not manipulated!

As you can see in Tomas Chabada's answer he creates new objects only containing questions with "test" in `select new { c, cd, cda }`.

Comment: Wow this is so cool!! Will try this on my end. Thank you @Dominik

Comment: This will however return collection containing only `Compliance` entities. But the OP was selecting * in the original SQL so the row represented all 3 objects.

Comment: @TomasChabada You are right. This will return all `Compliance`s with questions containing "test". The `Compliance` objects are not manipulated. I'll add that to my answer but leave it there since I think having the comparison between LINQ and System.Linq is good to see.